# react-admin-import-csv customize success notification

Tags: javascript, react-admin

In my react-admin application I am using react-admin-import-csv to import CSV files. When the import is with errors I do something like:

```
notify(`importError`, { type: 'error', messageArgs: { error: resultMessage }, multiLine: true })
throw new Error(errors);
```

This works fine and I get an error notification as expected.

But when the import is successful and I do something like:

```
notify(`importSuccess`, { type: 'success', messageArgs: { success: success }, multiLine: true, autoHideDuration:3000});
return;
```

The result is that my success notification is hidden right away by react-admin-import-csv default notification.

The only workaround that I found is throwing a "success error" instead of a simple return. It shows the success notification successfully but with an error in the console:

[image: Console Error]

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommand throwing a "success" error because when you do so you don't let react-admin-import-csv finish its work properly.

The best I could do is to internationalize the success message like the following:

```
en: {
    csv: {
        dialogImport: {
            alertClose: "result.importSuccessLib",
            title: "Importation of users",
        },
        dialogCommon: {
            subtitle: "Importation of %{count} element(s) from %{fileName}",
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have:

```
en: {
    result: {
        importSuccessLib: 'File imported successfully'
    }
}
```

I hope it can help someone.